# Is it possible to pass a variable/helper as argument when inserting a template?

Tags: templates, meteor, helper, meteoric

I'm developping an hybrid App based on Meteor with Meteoric (http://meteoric.github.io/). But I think the problem doubt I'm having is more general.

I have a template called AppLayout (AppLayout.html/AppLayout.js) used as a layout for the whole App. Basically it has the tabbar on it:

```
<template name="appLayout">

  {{#ionBody}}
    {{> ionNavBar }}

    {{#ionNavView}}
      {{> yield}}
    {{/ionNavView}}


    {{#ionTabs style="ios"}}
        {{> ionTab title="Home" path="pictures" iconOff="ios-home-outline" iconOn="ios-home"}}
        {{> ionTab title="Notificaciones" path=notificationsId iconOff="android-notifications-none" iconOn="android-notifications"}}
        {{> ionTab title="Locales" path="places" iconOff="ios-world-outline" iconOn="ios-world"}}
        {{> ionTab title="Mi Actividad" path="activity" iconOff="ios-list-outline" iconOn="ios-list"}}
        {{> ionTab title="Perfil" path="profile" iconOff="ios-person-outline" iconOn="ios-person"}}
    {{/ionTabs}}

  {{/ionBody}}

</template>
```

My problem is that I need one of the ionTab icons to have a path that it's not constant.

```
{{> ionTab title="Notificaciones" path=notificationsId iconOff="android-notifications-none" iconOn="android-notifications"}}
```

To do so, I have the variable "notificationsId" declared in the helpers section of the Template:

```
Template.appLayout.helpers({
    notificationsId : function() {
        var id = "0";

        if(Meteor.user()){
            id = Meteor.user()._id;
        }

        return "notifications/"+id;
    }   
});
```

But it doesn't work and I can't find a way to pass a variable to the ionTab helper.

Answer (score 0):

[This example](http://meteorcapture.com/spacebars/#template-inclusion-ex-3) seems to match the pattern you're using, namely a helper that returns a variable which is then used as a named parameter for a template.